# DataGridTemplateColumn and Binding Error? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of a binding error I am getting.

However, I must stipulate that that the binding is working correctly in both cases below, but I seem to always get a warning error in XAML.

The code below, does not create the error in XAML and as I said above, the binding works as it should. Binding to `dDate` works as it should.

```
   <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Header="Day" 
         SortMemberPath="dDate" IsReadOnly="True" 
         Binding="{Binding Path=dDate,
                   StringFormat={}{0:ddd}}" />
```

But, if I use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and bind to `dDate` , I get an error in the XAML, but as stated earlier, everything binds as it should.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" Header="Day"
          SortMemberPath="dDate" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
                 Text="{Binding Path=dDate,
                        StringFormat={}{0:ddd}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And I get this error,

[image]

I am not sure if I should even really be trying to work out why this error occurs as the binding is working, but I can't just seem to let it go.

Any reason why this would happen?

EDIT: I should mention that this also happens in any other column that uses `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Comment: Gotta laugh, posted for 5 seconds and a down vote, did the down voter even read the question??? If he/she did, faster reader than the flash...

Comment: If the binding works at runtime you have nothing to worry about. The XAML designer is simply not smart enough to handle all scenarios. This seems to be related to Reflector?

Comment: @mm8, yep, everything works as it should. But, I can't seem to let it go ( the error that is). I hate seeing that little wavy line under the property. What is Reflector?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Resharper.It is an extension for Visual Studio that comes with these kind of squiggly lines.

Comment: @mm8, Yeah, I am using ReSharper.

Comment: I though so. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: There's a spelling error : `dDate` or `dData` ?

Comment: @jstreet, yes it was supossed to be `dDate`

Comment: ReShaper is simply wrong about the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binding works at runtime you have nothing to worry about.

It is most probably `ReSharper` that adds these squiggly lines for some reason. You will probably have to learn to live with them or uninstall `ReSharper` :)

Comment: Looks like resharper has a way to disable it. I don't use resharper but I saw this question this morning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654097/animating-solidcolorbrush-in-background and the answer had this in it:  <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved --> Might need to change the BindingWithContextNotResolved part though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use DataType to define used binding type.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyType">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Or you can use relative source

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"></TextBlock>
```

Or you can use design time

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyType}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately none of those work. BTW, if you look at the error message, I am already defining d:DataContext in the XAML file as you have posted.

Comment: The first solution `DataType=` works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for with exactly the same problem as OP (ie not sure why someone thinks it doesn't work)